# On .Net Core need to run python command before main.py scrpt

Tags: c#, python-3.x, .net-core, ubuntu-18.04

Here is the problem.

I need to run some python file using C# .Net core on ubuntu WSL.(Install Ubuntu on windows machine and run C# dll inside Ubuntu using `DotNet file.dll` with is running python file inside)

I need to run below command before actual main.py file run.

```
python3 -m pip install --user virtualenv 
python3 -m venv env 
pip install -r requirements.txt
source env/bin/activate
```

I am using below code in C# to run python

```
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "main.py",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            };

using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
            {
                using (StreamWriter reader = process.StandardInput) {
                    reader.WriteLine("pip install --upgrade pip");
                }
                using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                {
                    //result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    process.WaitForExit();
                    Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90)).Wait();
                }
            }
```

But its always failing. Any suggesting highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have error message? Exception? Exit code with command output?

Comment: But is this the correct way to do it.